# Structuring Google Cloud Functions project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-architecture

I have a REST API that I'd like to port to run as a collection of cloud functions. I'm wondering how to split up the different endpoints in the best way, and how much to rename endpoints to fit the GCF model.

For example, I have the following types of request.

```
GET /images
GET /images/<image_id>
POST /images
```

If this was implemented with GCF, these would all fall under the same function `images`, and then I would need to implement some routing based on HTTP method, plus a pattern match for `<image_id>`, etc..

I could however choose to implement something like...

```
GET /images
GET /image/<image_id>
POST /createImage
```

...so that each endpoint has a distinct function that is invoked. This seems more appropriate from a cloud functions point of view, but not at all appropriate from a RESTful design point of view.

What are the trade-offs for implementing cloud functions in one or the other of these ways?

Comment: A little late... but I'm curious if you figured out a solution. I'm in the process of porting over an API as well and I'm unclear on the best approach here. Doesn't seem like a natural fit.